# android studio webview progress bar

Tags: progress

progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.prg);

webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

```
        @Override public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            setTitle("Loading...");
        }
        @Override public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            setTitle(view.getTitle());
        }
```

Comment: Is this a "suggest a question" competition?

Comment: It's My Solved Answer. for future ‍save.